# If $n^2+n+1>2^m$, for some integer $m$ and $C$ can correct $2$ error, show that $k<n-m+1$.

Tags: solution-verification, coding-theory

Let $C$ be a binary linear $(n,k)$-code over $F$. If $n^2+n+1>2^m$, for some integer $m$ and $C$ can correct $2$ error, show that $k<n-m+1$.

**Attempt:**
Since $C$ is $2$-error-correcting, by the [Hamming bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound), we have
$$|C| \le \frac{2^n}{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2}} = \frac{2^{n+1}}{n^2+n+2}.$$
On the other hand, $|C|=2^k$.
Hence,
$$2^k \le \frac{2^{n+1}}{n^2+n+2} < \frac{2^{n+1}}{n^2+n+1} < \frac{2^{n+1}}{2^m}.$$
Thus, $k < n-m+1$.

Am I true? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, except you have an error (extra $+n$) in the denominator of
$$
|C|\leq \frac{2^n}{n^2+2n+2}
$$
which is then corrected in the next equation.